# error while creating virtualbox host-only interface

Tags: genymotion

After running this command `sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtual box-dkms` I get the error

```
0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for virtual box-dkms:amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your command, it's `sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms`

Comment: I have tried that command but it's giving me this 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for virtualbox-dkms:amd64

Comment: Have you installed virtualbox first (`sudo apt install virtualbox`)? Also, what distribution do you use?